# Removendo o "\n" de uma string lida usando fgets()

Tags: c

Geralmente quando se usa a função fgets() ela lê a string porém é sensível ao Enter, como ler a string ser adicionar a ela o "\n"??

Answer (score 4):

Uma coisa que você pode fazer é ler a string com o `'\n'` e apagá-lo depois, escrevendo um '\0' no lugar do `\n`.

Outra coisa que você pode fazer é ler a string letra por letra, via getcha. Assim você tem controle total sobre o que você escreve na sua string.

Answer (score 4):

A maneira melhor, na minha opinião, é ler a string completa e depois remover o `'\n'`

```
char input[1000];
size_t len;
if (!fgets(input, sizeof input, stdin)) { /* tratamento de erro */ }
len = strlen(input);
if (len == 0) { /* normalmente isto nunca acontece */ }

/* alguns "ficheiros de texto" nao tem '\n' na ultima linha */
if (input[len - 1] == '\n') input[--len] = 0; // remove '\n' e actualiza len
```

Answer (score 4):

A função `fgets()` é semelhante à função `gets()`, porém, além dela poder fazer a leitura a partir de um arquivo de dados e incluir o caracter de nova linha na string, ela ainda especifica o tamanho máximo da string de entrada, a função `gets()` não tem este controle, o que poderia acarretar erros de "estouro de buffer".

Para remover o '\n' você pode fazer da seguinte maneira:

```
minhaString[strcspn(minhaString, "\n")] = 0;
```

[Fonte](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2693776/removing-trailing-newline-character-from-fgets-input).

Comment: E se a string não tiver ENTER (ultima linha dum ficheiro de texto (incompleto)) essa instrução limpa a string toda.

Comment: Isso só acontece quando se trabalha com arquivo? Eu usei esta implementação para remover o ENTER do `fgets()` quando recebe valor do teclado e funcionou, mas eu não sei quando que acontece esta situação de limpar a string toda se não tiver o ENTER.

Comment: Hmmm erro meu ... estava a interpretar mal o `strcspn()`. `strcspn("teste", "\n")` devolve `5` e portanto a tua expressão funciona bem em todos os casos. Aceita as minhas desculpas.

Comment: Não precisa se desculpar ta tranquilo, sua intenção era boa.

Answer (score 1):

Para remover o '\n' do final da string, tente isto:

```
size_t ln = strlen(input) - 1;
if (name[ln] == '\n')
    name[ln] = '\0';
```

Fonte: https://stackoverflow.com/a/2693827/194717

ou isto:

```
char *pos;
if ((pos=strchr(input, '\n')) != NULL)
    *pos = '\0';
```

Fonte: https://stackoverflow.com/a/2693826/194717

Answer (score 1):

Uma vez lida a String você pode usar métodos da classe String.
Ex.:

```
string teste;
FILE arquivo;
arquivo = fopen("arquivo.txt" , "r");
if( fgets (teste, [tamanho do arquivo], arquivo)!=NULL ) {
  puts(teste);
}
fclose(arquivo);
string testeSemN = teste.Replace("\n", String.Empty);
// ou também: teste.Replace("\n", "");
```

Comment: Em C não há classes, nem `string`, nem métodos.

Comment: Tens razão @pmg. Me equivoquei na resposta. Ela se aplica a C# e não C...
Encontrei duas funções como alternativas que talvez ajudem. Não tenho como testar agora como elas vão se comportar com o "\n". Mas seguem os links: http://creativeandcritical.net/str-replace-c/ e http://www.binarytides.com/str_replace-for-c/