# Lendo arquivo em Objective C

Tags: c, objective-c, fopen

Estou tentando ler um arquivo em .c, eu consigo ler até ai tudo certo porém na variável ele me retorna um todo o conteúdo e um "\n" que prejudica o resto do meu código. Segue abaixo o trecho que efetua a leitura do txt para que vocês analisem.

```
char * info_conta(char *cpf,int line)
{
//Declaro variaveis para ler o arquivo
char contacaminho[80]="contas/",linha[80], cpf2[14];
strcpy(cpf2,cpf);
int id = 1;


//Concatenho com a pasta e o numero do cpf para carregar os dados
//strcpy(contacaminho, "contas/");
strcat(contacaminho, cpf2);
strcat(contacaminho,".dat");

//Crio uma variavel do tipo FILE para ler o arquivo
FILE *arquivo = fopen(contacaminho,"r");

//Crio um laço de repetição para ler o arquivo
while(fgets(linha, 80, arquivo) != NULL)
{
    if(id == line)
    {
        // Paro o laço de repetição e mantenho o valor da variavel.
        break;
    }
    id++; // Aumento o valor da chave identificadora em + 1;
}


fclose(arquivo); // Fecho o arquivo

return linha; // retorno as infromações
}
```

Comment: Essa questão é sobre `objective-c` ou `c`?

Comment: Coloquei a *tag* Objective C já que você cita no título, mas ter certeza que tem alguma coisa a ver com esta linguagem?

Comment: "Prejudica todo o meu código" pode significar muita coisa. Seja mais claro: o que espera acontecer? o que esta acontecendo?

Comment: .c é a extensão que salvo, sobre o "prejudica" é o seguinte eu espero concatenar o valor ai como ele vem com o \n ele não mostra os outros dados concatenados pois estou usando o comando system() e dou um title por exemplo.

Comment: Duplicada de [Removendo o “\n” de uma string lida usando fgets()](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/32638).

Comment: Perdão mais não tem nada a ver pmg, o cara tá usando um fgets eu estou lendo um arquivo de texto.

Answer (score 1):

Você pode usar `strtok`:

```
while(fgets(linha, 80, arquivo) != NULL)
{
    strtok(linha, "\n");
    //...resto do seu código
}
```

Ou mesmo partir para a *força bruta*:

```
while(fgets(linha, 80, arquivo) != NULL)
{
    size_t pos = strlen(linha) - 1;
    if (linha[pos] == '\n')
    {
        linha[pos] = '\0';
    }
    //...resto do seu código
}
```

Comment: Sergio irei fazer o teste hoje assim que chegar da faculdade anoite, se funcionar eu te aviso obrigado.