# Não está parando de processar arquivo

Tags: c

Por que é que não esta parando com a comparação?

```
/*7.    Faça um programa que leia uma sequência de nomes no formato “nome sobrenome” e armazene-os em um arquivo texto.
 A lista de nomes termina com um nome igual ao ponto.*/

#include<stdio.h>
#include<string.h>

char const FIM[] = ".";

int main()
{
    FILE *arq;
    char nomeS[70];
    char *ret;

    arq = fopen("arquivoGerado07.txt","w");

    puts("Insira um nome e sobrenome: ");
    ret = fgets(nomeS,sizeof(nomeS), stdin);

    while(strcmp(FIM,nomeS) != 0)
    {
        fputs(ret,arq);
        puts("Insira um nome e sobrenome: ");
        ret = fgets(nomeS,sizeof(nomeS),stdin);
    }
    fclose(arq);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Pergunta relacionada: ['Removendo o “\n” de uma string lida usando fgets()'](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/32638/215)

Answer (score 1):

Depois de ler a string com `fgets()` remove de la o `'\n'`.

```
ret = fgets(nomeS,sizeof(nomeS), stdin);
if (ret == NULL) /* erro */;
nomelen = strlen(nomeS);
if (nomelen == 0) /* erro estranho */;
if (nomeS[nomelen - 1] == '\n') {
    nomeS[--nomelen] = 0; /* remove '\n' e actualiza nomelen */
}
```

Comment: Se esse código for executado numa plataforma Windows, ainda assim somente um `\n` irá parar na variável? (em vez de um `\r\n` por exemplo? E se a *stream* de entrada não for o *stdin*, e sim um arquivo cuja quebra de linha é um `\r\n`?

Comment: P.S. [Confirmei aqui](http://stackoverflow.com/a/12769646/520779) que ele lê sim o `\r` (em arquivos, pelo menos, não sei quanto ao *stdin*).

Comment: Outro problema: se a string lida tiver `69` caracteres ele não vai incluir o `\n` no final. Veja [esse thread](http://cboard.cprogramming.com/c-programming/72927-fgets-will-always-return-%5Bstring%5D%5Cn%5C0.html) pra mais detalhes. Sendo assim, é melhor só executar essa última linha se ficar confirmado que o `nomeS[nomelen-1]` é mesmo um `\n`.

Comment: Se o arquivo tiver sido aberto em modo texto (`"r"`, `"r+"`, ...) ele não lê o `'\r'` (o `stdin` é aberto em modo texto).

Comment: Obrigado pelo nota dos 69 caracteres. Snippet alterado.

Comment: Obrigado pelo esclarecimento! Fiquei na dúvida porque, segundo [essa resposta](http://stackoverflow.com/a/19044200/520779), se for utilizado o compilador GNU - que não faz diferença entre o modo binário e o modo texto - numa plataforma Windows, o `\r` seria lido independentemente do modo (de novo, em arquivos, não sabia se isso se aplicava ao `stdin` ou não).

Comment: O problema dessa resposta não é tanto o compilador, mas sim a biblioteca, ou seja, misturar um compilador Windows com uma biblioteca Linux. Nota que `fputc('\n', arquivo);` pode escrever 2 bytes em Windows, se `arquivo` tiver sido aberto em modo texto.

Answer (score 0):

De acordo com [essa documentação](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/fgets/), o `fgets` **inclui** a quebra de linha lida da *stream* (i.e. quando você dá <kbd>Enter</kbd>) na sua saída - ao contrário do [`gets`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/gets/), que não inclui. Assim, a string lida jamais será igual a `"."` - no máximo será `".\n"`, `".\r"` ou `".\r\n"`, [dependendo da plataforma](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12769646/520779) (*Nota*: pelo menos isso ocorre na leitura de arquivos - não estou certo se a leitura do *stdin* leva ou não em conta a quebra de linha padrão da plataforma ou se usa `\n` sempre).

Para fins do seu exercício, creio que a melhor saída é usar `gets` mesmo, apesar do perigo de *overflow*:

```
ret = gets(nomeS);
```

Na prática, entretanto, o ideal seria ou normalizar o valor lido ou testar pelas 3 variantes, o que for mais fácil (tenho pouca experiência prática em C, então não posso ajudar nesse sentido).

Comment: Esse `-1` é por eu sugerir usar um `gets`? Ou tem alguma outra coisa errada na resposta?